# How to pipeline log/txt file in logstash to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

So, basically i have a single log or a text file that i want to visualize using ELK. I am able to setup elasticsearch and kibana on the system. This is my logstash config file right now.

```
input { file {
    path => "G:/everything.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
} }

filter {

}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "example" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

when in browser I open http://localhost:9200/ this is what appears

```
{
  "name" : "1rtH6q6",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "oicreqLyQ_iNiTrOQ0sYPQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.1",
    "build_hash" : "2cfe0df",
    "build_date" : "2017-05-29T16:05:51.443Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

in my kibana console after executing GET /_cat/indices?v&pretty

```
health status index          uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   .kibana        fxFjIS55Q9-qAgqLlPE0Cw   1   1          2            0      6.3kb          6.3kb
yellow open   windows_events YUBWMzRpRTmEdu6E2UoCXg   5   1          2            0     12.6kb         12.6kb
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Okay, So i basically want to visualize my error logs in my logs file using ELK.......Please help me step by step if possible

Comment: What happens if you open Kibana on http://localhost:5601 ?

Comment: it asks to create a new index pattern

Comment: Then create one with the name of the index (`windows_events`?)

Comment: create new index pattern where ..... in kibana itself??

Comment: Everything is pretty well explained in the doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html

Comment: But for my log file i have mentioned "example" as my index and it is unable to fetch that

Comment: Apparently your index is called `windows_events` judging from what you get from `/_cat/indices`

Comment: i deleted windows_events and ran logstash again ....... it does not exists that means the index is not windows_event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you need to do couple of things in order to display your logs in Kibana.

1) Based on your log pattern, you have to write appropriate grok pattern to parse your log file. You can also use [Grok Debugger utility](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to write grok pattern for your log.

E.g. For Apache access log grok pattern would be

```
   filter {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
      }
      date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      }
    }
```

I would recommend you to read this [official guideline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html).

Once your log file parse correctly then you will see the data will index on your `example` Elasticsearch index.

For validate the data you can use below get command

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/example/_search'
```

2) In the next step, you have to configure default Elasticsearch index pattern in kibana. For reference read these reference

- [define Your Index Pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html).
- [Connect Kibana with Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/connect-to-elasticsearch.html#connect-to-elasticsearch)

Comment: How do i check whether my log file parses correctly??

Comment: Updated my answer, If your log file parsed correctly then your data will be indexed in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Okay...... so basically my log files are in this form
[06-19 14:47:48] p224 {ArduinoCommunicator.py:126} DEBUG - 10,0,0,0,0
[06-19 14:47:48] p224 {ArduinoCommunicator.py:162} INFO - [10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[06-19 14:47:48] p224 {ArduinoCommunicator.py:163} INFO - ['10', '0', '0', '0', '1']
[06-19 14:47:48] p224 {ArduinoCommunicator.py:128} DEBUG - Validated the received tuple
[06-19 14:47:48] p224 {ArduinoCommunicator.py:131} DEBUG - ['10', '0', '0', '0', '0']
[06-19 14:47:48] p224 {ArduinoCommunicator.py:126} DEBUG - 10,0,0,0,0

Comment: okay my log file format is in extremely raw ...... after reducing it to a simple log format I was able to achieve it .... Thank You so much !

Comment: Glad it helped you !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673016/filtering-log-file-in-logstash

hey can u help me in this situation as well